# Undefined property error while trying to create a new resource

Tags: laravel-nova

I get the `Undefined property App\Plan::$bandwidth` error when I try to create a new Resource or save the edited value.

However, values are listed fine for the same field during view/edit.

Here is the field definition:

`Number::make('Bandwidth', 'bandwidth')->min(0),`

Answer (score 5):

The model had a method with the same name. Works fine after the renaming the method. I wonder if this is a bug.

Comment: Same issue here. You ever found a way to resolve this issue without having to rename the method?

Comment: Have you tried v1.2.1? https://nova.laravel.com/releases It seems to address many known issues. I still think it's not production-ready.

Comment: @Farveaz No. I don't think so. I haven't tried it with 1.3.2 though. Too many issues, had to put off using Nova for production unfortunately.

Comment: Encountered and it is not seen as a Nova bug : https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/989
Workaround is to set a default value in the model :
`protected $attributes = ['bandwidth'=> 0, ...];
function bandwidth() { ... }`